# Memory usage implications of biderectional caching

Tags: java, pointers, caching, memory

I would like to know the memory usage implications of the below code snippet. My understanding is that only one instance of each will be stored in memory and every addition to the second cache will be merely creating a pointer. If a pointer is created how much space is consumed? Is there any way to monitor what happens in the JVM and memory usage for the below example? Would it be necessary to intern the uid? Any advice on the below would be appreciated.

```
//Bidirectional Cache
HashMap<String, Long> cache1 = new HashMap<String, Long>();
HashMap<Long, String> cache2 = new HashMap<Long, String>();

//Some Random Test Data
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    Long id = new Long(i);
    String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    cache1.put(uid, id);
    cache2.put(id , uid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object reference takes at most 8 bytes on a 64-bit JVM, but thanks to [CompressedOops](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fi/2012/06/what-is-xxusecompressedoops-in-64-bit.html) 4 bytes. Since you have only 100000 objects, the map references will take 4*4*100000 = 1,6MB of memory. The map contents will take 100,000*(sizeof(UUID)+sizeof(Long)) which is still in the tens of megabytes.

Interning helps with identical Strings, one of the `U`s in `UUID` tells you why that won't help you. Not that you really need help. A tiny map of 100k entries doesn't warrant any special attention.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Indeed the intern is not useful in the given snippet. This was mentioned though because if the cache is expanded even further. Depending on the expanding approach a new string uid might be created and not shared via the pointer, which I will try to avoid of course.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a Bidirectional Map API instead of maintaining two maps yourself. For example, take a look at [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface provided by [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). The advantage of using a BiMap is: it will preserve the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys.

For cache1, you can simply do a `bimap.get(key)`. For cache2, you do `bimap.inverse().get(key)`.

Comment: While that's true, this doesn't really answer the question and is better as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) At this point in time I am merely looking at the code snippet to confirm I am not missing anything. More of a learning experience if you will.